# Haskell -- mapping function to permutation

Tags: haskell, dictionary, permutation

I defined function listToNumber as below:

```
listToNumber = foldl1 (\acc xs -> acc*10 + xs)
```

It works fine when only supplied with one numeric list, for example:

```
listToNumber [1,2,3,4] = 1234
map listToNumber [[1,2,3,4], [5,4,3,2]] = [1234,5432]
```

However, the following returns error message:

```
map listToNumber permutations[1..3]
```

can someone explain please?

P.S. the error msg is as below:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[t1] -> t0' with actual type `[b0]'
The function `map' is applied to three arguments,
but its type `([b0] -> b0) -> [[b0]] -> [b0]' has only two
In the expression: map listToNumber permutations [1 .. 3]
In an equation for `it':
    it = map listToNumber permutations [1 .. 3]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try `map listToNumber (permutations [1 .. 3])`

in ghci you can check the type of a function or an expression with `:t`

```
> :t map
> map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

im means `map` requires a function and  a list and returns a list, but in `map listToNumber permutations [1 .. 3]` you try to pass two functions and a list to map 
(since function application associates to the left).

Answer (score 0):

Another variant: `map listToNumber $ permutations [1..3]`.